# Angularjs, Express infinite loop from improper static route, but then MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, express

This problem goes in a full circle and it's not just about the infinite loop. I am using Angularjs `html5Mode`, and Express catch-all route `/*`. When I request a page, an infinite loops begins because Express cannot find the static assets route, which triggers the catch-all route, which gets served to the client. This repeats since I am sending my index.html.

That's the first part of the problem, and it exists in this code:

express app:

```
// Serve static files
app.use('/static', express.static(config.PUBLIC));

/* ...
   ... define app routes
   ...
*/ 

// catch all route
app.use('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(config.PUBLIC + "index.html");
});
```

The index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <base href="/"></base>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- main html body code -->

    <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/other.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Angularjs:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true});

// other routes
// $stateProvider.....
```

Eventually, you'll get an error that says:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

**To fix this**, I added a wildcard to the Express `/static` route:

```
app.use('/static/*', express.static(config.PUBLIC));
```

This works as it triggers the static route rather than the catch-all route. However the browser now results in a bunch of these errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:1234/static/js/app.js/".

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

... And so on.

Now I'm stumped. How do I serve my static files?